# How to keep only visible part of path?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I'm editing an image using Inkscape like this:

[image: image with strokes only]

Since I have painted image, how can I cut out all the extra strokes (actually whole image are path, including strokes) and creating a new path with only necessary part like this:

[image: colored image]

Comment: Fill the path with white?

Answer (score 2):

One method is to draw a secondary path to cut another in two.

In Inkscape use the Bezier tool to draw a path where you want to cut it. Select both paths, and click *Path > Cut Path*

[image]

Another method is to fill the shapes with white, and then change the order in the stack by using *Object > Raise/Lower*, etc.  There are also buttons for these operations on the tool bar in the Move tool options along the top.

[image]